# unable to add SerpConnection for promptflow in VSCode

Tags: azure-openai, serpapi, azure-promptflow

I am working on creating a promptflow in VSCode. where I need to create the Serp Api Connection. I have added the connection and the same is visible when I try to get the list of connection.
[image]

However when I try to select the connection on the promptflow. I still get 'No Connections available'. Am I missing something here.
[image]